# PHP + JS Modal - show value in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am grabbing data from a MySQL query and am now trying to display it in `<input>` fields in my modal by letting JS put it there , but for whatever reason I am unable to handover the variables into the modal. I frankly have no clue of Javascript, hence suspect an issue there.

PHP generated HTML button:

```
<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#edit\" data-id=\"$id\" data-date=\"$date\">Edit</button></td>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <?php
                echo "
                    <td>ID No.: </td><input name=\"dataID\" value=\"\" /></td>
                    <td>Date: </td><input name=\"dataDate\" value=\"\" /></td>";
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.Modal -->
```

Javascript:

```
    <script>
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var dataID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataID"]').val(dataID);
    var dataDate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataDate"]').val(dataDate);
});
</script>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: why don't you put the data directly in the modal body??

Comment: because I have hundreds of entries and each comes with each own edit button, which is then supposed to load my modal. If I dont do the JS solution, I cannot handover the correct $id / $date variable into the input fields, instead it would always only return the variable of the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code works for me, please right click -> "view sourse" to make sure $id and $date are printed at:

```
data-id=\"$id\" data-date=\"$date\"
```

```js
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var dataID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataID"]').val(dataID);
    var dataDate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataDate"]').val(dataDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-id="abcabc" data-date="12-03-2014">Edit</button>



<!-- Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Details</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>ID No.: </td><input name="dataID" value="" /></td>
                                           <td>Date: <input name="dataDate" value="" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.Modal -->
```

Comment: source prints the variables correctly, just to make sure I ran it through a jsfiddle and it also works. seems like the problem is related to my website / webhost. What references should I include to run the code? Google Ajax, min-jquery, bootstrap, anything else?

Comment: Alright, I was playing around with the code and can confirm that it works on JSfiddle.net, but i am unable to make it work on my website. What could the reason for that be? I am using jquery 2.2.0 and bootstrap 3.3.6.